# Position divs as follow without float

Tags: html, css

I have a web page which looks like this :

[image: What I want]

I would like to know if it is possible to have different margin-top value for the 2 outer divs. At the moment, whether I set margin : x% or margin : [value]px  both outer div will receive the value from the margin. I would like it to affect only the one I set.

I mention without float because I was having problem with float and margin / width properties, but if you can come up with a proper solution using float, that'll float my boat. :)

Thanks a lot.

I'm a CSS newbie by the way so be easy on me

Comment: Please post code (preferably in a fiddle).

Comment: the first image is what you have and the second one what you want to achive ?

Comment: It's just 1 image. So I have 2 div side by side, but I don't them at the same X position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like this ?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J9BA6/1/)**

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="aaa">first</div>
    <div class="bbb">second</div>
    <div class="ccc">third</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="aaa">first</div>
    <div class="bbb">second</div>
    <div class="ccc">third</div>
</div>
```

css

```
div:not(.container){
    margin: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
    background: white;
    height: 100px;
}

.container{
    float: left;
    background: black;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 25px; /*sets both divs same top*/
}

.container:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: 50px;   
    /*margin-top: 25px*/ /*sets only second div or all others down and leaves
                           the first div like it is. but this for you have to
                           delete the margin-top entry from .container{  */
}
```

but actually i would use diffrent classes for this so you can set every div with his own css configuration :)

like:

```
.myFirstDivContainer{
    /* pos data here */
}
.mySecondDivContainer{
    /* pos data here */
}
```

and so on

**EDIT**

see **[:not() compabilitys](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)**

you can also use `:nth-child()` like

```
div.container:nth-child(0){
    /* data for your first div */
}

div.container:nth-child(1){
    /* data for your second div */
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Yes, something like this :) I need to be able to position all the divs inside as I like too. This seemed to do the trick though thanks.
Do you know if :not(:firstChild) and so on are compatible cross-browsers and older version of IE?

Comment: @BenLefebvre depends on what you mean with older versions. i added a link at the bottom of my post with the compabilitys.

Answer (score 1):

Something just as good as margin-top in your case might be:

```
.second-div {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}
```

This will move the second div 15px down relative to its default position.

BTW, you should get used to JSFiddle, it's a very good prototyping tool, and far better than making non-interactive drawings :)

[Here's your drawing as a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/54zvD/)

Comment: Thanks for th answer, is there a certain drawback to using position :relative? Will the position stay there if I change my browser window size and stuff like that?

Comment: Yes, the only "drawback" is that it takes the element out of the flow (relatively); learn more about positioning: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yeah, I should get used to jsFiddle, it comes in handy to demonstrate problems.

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple css classes in the class attribute on an html element:

```
<div class="outer-div-wrapper">some content</div>
<div class="outer-div-wrapper larger-margin">some content</div>
```

then put in place some css rules:

```
/* this will give all divs with class 'outer-div-wrapper' a margin-top of 10px */
.outer-div-wrapper {
  margin-top: 10px; 
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-right: 10px;
} 
/* This will increase the margin size for the divs with the extra 'larger-margin' class */
.outer-div-wrapper.larger-margin {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```